# Arranging objects in blender in a heap

Tags: objects

I have a model of a plate and now I want to place some pasta on it.

Now, I have created an object of pasta and now I want to make the plate *filled* with pasta, like a *heap*. How should I do that?

I have tried to place each pasta-piece in the plate, but that is just too tiresome. Also, I was unable to make use of particle system to achieve this.

Comment: Hello :). I'm not expert on rendering pasta ([unlike our very own Mr. Duarte](https://pasta.duarteramos.pt/)). But particle systems or geometry nodes are the way to go :).

Comment: Oh, Wow! That @Duarte chart is magnificent! I never knew!

Comment: wow a nice way to learn how to model anything  ^^

Comment: ok but how can you create a website about italian pastas and choose a ".pt" domain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

- Apply the scales of your objects
- Give you plate a *Physics > Rigid Body > Type > Passive* and *Collisions > Shape > Mesh*
- Give your pasta a *Physics > Rigid Body > Type > Active* and *Collisions > Shape > Convex Hull*
- *Linked-Duplicate* your pasta with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
- Select all your pastas, go into *Object > Transform > Randomize Transform* and in the *Operator* box tweak the parameters a bit
- Play the animation, the pastas should fall into the plate
- Select them all and *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes* and choose the frame where you want to freeze the animation
- Eat while it's hot

Comment: This was super-useful! Thank you!

Comment: I guess that it should be *Rigid Body* instead of *Animation* in the second-last point

Comment: yes you're right, thanks, Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes